# SwiftData is failing to retrieve saved data and appears to be using an incorrect SQL index name

Tags: swift, sqlite, swift-data

I have two models that are have a weird interaction:

```swift
@Model public final class Position: Equatable, Identifiable {
  var zone: ZoneModel?
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Item.positions) 
  var items = [Item]()
  var name: String = ""
  var weight: Int = 0
  var weightAllowed: Int = 0
  
  init(name: String, weightAllowed: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.weightAllowed = weightAllowed
  }
}

@Model public final class Item: Equatable, Identifiable {
  var form: FormModel?
  var positions: [Position]()
  var count: Int = 0
  var weight: Int = 0

  init() {}
}
```

There are many other tables that are all connected, but these are the ones where the problems arise. The `PositionModel` is able to properly store and persist the `items: [ItemModel]` variable, but the `ItemModel` runs into a problem after the app closes.

I am getting this error in my SQL Stack Trace

> no such column: t1.Z_6POSITIONS in
> "SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK
> FROM Z_5POSITIONS t1
> JOIN ZPOSITION t0
> ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_6POSITIONS
> WHERE t1.Z_5ITEMS = ? "

When looking at my sqlite database I see that the table name is not `Z_5POSITIONS.Z_6POSITIONS`, but it is `Z_5POSITIONS.Z_7POSITIONS`.

Index T-SQL:

```sql
CREATE INDEX "Z_5POSITIONS_Z_7POSITIONS_INDEX" ON "Z_5POSITIONS" (
    "Z_7POSITIONS",
    "Z_5ITEMS"
);
```

For extra context here is the SQL Stack Trace:

```
CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/Users/dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9AF36251-51EF-43D8-BD9B-34A498B4EC83/data/Containers/Data/Application/E063C2DB-1FF0-42D8-BEAC-CBD75CE50E60/Library/Application Support/default.store"
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
TraceSQL(0x110e76a60): SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: pragma recursive_triggers=1
TraceSQL(0x110e76a60): pragma recursive_triggers=1
CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
TraceSQL(0x110e76a60): pragma journal_mode=wal
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_5POSITIONS t1 JOIN ZPOSITION t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_6POSITIONS WHERE t1.Z_5ITEMS = ? 
no such column: t1.Z_6POSITIONS in "SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_5POSITIONS t1 JOIN ZPOSITION t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_6POSITIONS WHERE t1.Z_5ITEMS = ? "
CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database due to an error.
```

I have on automatic save, and also just to be sure and test it I am manually saving the added on ItemModel object. Every other SwiftData object is being properly saved, including the Items to the Position side to the many-to-many relationship, but the inverse isn't working.

```swift
Header(vm: vm, onSubmit: {
  if vm.selected == nil {
    vm.new.updateWeight(with: oc)
    report.form?.addItem(vm.new)
    do {
      try context.save()
      Logger.write("Save Successful.")
    } catch {
      Logger.write("Save error: \(error)")
    }
    vm.new = ItemModel()
    } else { vm.selected = nil }
})
.padding(.vertical, 10)
```

I always get a successful save. But every time I close and reopen the app I run into the above issue.

Does anyone have any insight into this or maybe can spot something I have wrong off a look?

Comment: vm.new is an instance of Item that I populate then assign to form.items using the addItem(_ item: Item) function that is a part of the Form model. 

Once i've saved that information to form I create a new instance of Item for vm.new so that the user can input new values and then eventually append that new item to report.form.items array as well.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson,

Do you have a possible alternative to that? I do it so it rests the binding for the view.